# Replace newlines between two words

Tags: awk

I have a output from a text file as below. I want to put all the contents of the someItems array under one line. So, every line would have the contents of a new someItems array. For example :

```
"someItems": [
{
  "someId": "MountSomers-showtime.com-ETTI0000000000000003-1452005472058",
  "source": "MountSomers",
  "sourceAssetId": "9",
  "title": "Pk_3",
  "ppp": "12",
  "expirationDate": "2016-01-06T14:51:12Z"
},    {
  "someId": "MountSomers-ericsson.com- ETTI0000000000000005-1452005472058",
  "source": "MountSomers",
  "sourceAssetId": "12",
  "title": "Pk_5",
  "ppp": "12",
  "expirationDate": "2016-01-06T14:51:12Z"
}  ]
"someItems": [
{
  "someId": "MountSomers-hbo.com-ETTI0000000000000002-1452005472058",
  "source": "MountSomers",
  "sourceAssetId": "7",
  "title": "Pk_2",
  "ppp": "12",
  "expirationDate": "2016-01-06T14:51:12Z"
},    {
  "someId": "MountSomers-showtime.com-ETTI0000000000000003-1452005472058",
  "source": "MountSomers",
  "sourceAssetId": "9",
  "title": "Pk_3",
  "ppp": "12",
  "expirationDate": "2016-01-06T14:51:12Z"
},    {
  "someId": "MountSomers-ericsson.com-ETTI0000000000000005-1452005472058",
  "source": "MountSomers",
  "sourceAssetId": "12",
  "title": "Pk_5",
  "ppp": "12",
  "expirationDate": "2016-01-06T14:51:12Z"
}  ]
```

would become

```
"someItems": [ ..... ]
"someItems": [ ..... ]
```

I have the below

```
cat file | | awk '/^"someItems": [/{p=1}/^]/{p=0} {if(p)printf "%s",$0;else printf "%s%s\n",(NR==1?"":RS),$0}'
```

but it does not do what I wanted...

Answer (score 1):

Since the input contains the brackets `[]` only in the outer level the solution can be pretty simple:

```
awk '{gsub("\n","", $0)}1' RS=']\n' file
```

I'm using `]\n` as the *input record separator*. This gives you the whole portion between `"someItems: ..."` until the closing `]` as `$0`. `gsub()` simply replaces the newlines. `1` prints the (modified) record.

---

You can also use `sed`:

```
sed '/\[/{:a;N;/]/!ba;s/\n//g}' file
```

I'll explain it in a multiline version:

*script.sed*:

```
# Address. Matches a line containing the opening [
/\[/ { # Start of block

    # Define a label 'a'
    :a

    # Read a new line and append it to the pattern buffer
    N

    # If the pattern buffer doens't contain the closing ]
    # jump back to label 'a'
    /]/!ba

    # Replace all newlines once the closing bracket appeared
    # Since we don't jump back to 'a' in this case, this means we'll
    # leave the block and start a new cycle.
    s/\n//g

} # End of block
```

Comment: awk solution is simple and straight forward. +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '/^"someItems":/ && f { printf "\n" } { printf $0; f=1 } END { printf "\n" }' file.txt
"someItems": [{  "someId": "MountSomers-showtime.com-ETTI0000000000000003-1452005472058",  "source": "MountSomers",  "sourceAssetId": "9",  "title": "Pk_3",  "ppp": "12",  "expirationDate": "2016-01-06T14:51:12Z"},    {  "someId": "MountSomers-ericsson.com- ETTI0000000000000005-1452005472058",  "source": "MountSomers",  "sourceAssetId": "12",  "title": "Pk_5",  "ppp": "12",  "expirationDate": "2016-01-06T14:51:12Z"}  ]
"someItems": [{  "someId": "MountSomers-hbo.com-ETTI0000000000000002-1452005472058",  "source": "MountSomers",  "sourceAssetId": "7",  "title": "Pk_2",  "ppp": "12",  "expirationDate": "2016-01-06T14:51:12Z"},    {  "someId": "MountSomers-showtime.com-ETTI0000000000000003-1452005472058",  "source": "MountSomers",  "sourceAssetId": "9",  "title": "Pk_3",  "ppp": "12",  "expirationDate": "2016-01-06T14:51:12Z"},    {  "someId": "MountSomers-ericsson.com-ETTI0000000000000005-1452005472058",  "source": "MountSomers",  "sourceAssetId": "12",  "title": "Pk_5",  "ppp": "12",  "expirationDate": "2016-01-06T14:51:12Z"}  ]
$
```

Print each line without a trailing newline. Starting with the second occurrence, put a leading newline before each `"someItems"`. Print a newline at the end to keep it classy.